# Does cloud foundry nodejs buildpack ignore the prepare script during `npm install`?

Tags: node.js, package.json, cloud-foundry, package-lock.json

I have a web app, nextjs, that gets deployed to Cloud Foundry through a Jenkins pipeline and using a `manifest.yml`.

In the manifest, I'm declaring it to use a `nodejs-buildpack`, and set the `command` field as `npm start`. During the deployment I noticed `npm install` takes places, but that triggers the `prepare` script in the `package.json`.

I want to skip this step, because that will install husky during deployment which is not needed. In the Jenkins pipeline, I can ignore that step during installation by setting this command, `npm ci --ignore-scripts`.

I'm noob at Cloud Foundry, so I'm not sure how to ignore the prepare script? I have looked at the docs but it's not really clear on how to tell `npm install` to ignore other scripts.

I don't think this is possible, but can you add multiple commands in the manifest command field?

If not, I was thinking of adding a bash script, `start.sh` where it will have multiple commands

start.sh

```
npm ci --ignore-scripts
npm run start
```

I guess in the `package.json`, the start script will be modified

package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
   "start": "bash ./start.sh",
   ...
}
```

So in the manifest, the command field will still the `npm start`

Is this a viable solution? Or is there a better solution to this without relying on a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your `prepare` script to skip husky installation for example by this:

```
"prepare": "node -e \"if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){process.exit(1)} \" || husky install"
```